# I recently saw a CSS file that has "body" and ".body" separately defined. Why put a description in the ".body" class?

Tags: html, css

It was something like below, but the weird thing is that body tag is the only element that is of class "body," so I'm not sure why.  Has anyone ran into anything similar?

```
body {
    background-image: url('img/bg2a.png');
    color: #000;
       ...
    }

.body {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: No havent seen that before and it is really unnecessary if it is only applied to the body.

Comment: Why don't you contact the owner of the site you came across and discuss with them why they did that?

Comment: The dot simply means that it's a class that can be used on any element...it's a poor name for a class, but it's permissible.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted (though the title needs to be fixed). It's a good question, which, although somewhat opinion-based, should have a reasonably general answer as to why someone would do this. I doubt that this is the only occurence of this practice.

Comment: It may be to minimize some javascript that goes along with the css.  For example, if it's a single page app, they might add the class "body" to <body> after you log in to change the layout from there-on without having to deal with each individual style.

Comment: The same CSS could be applied to other pages as well, where different elements (e.g. `div`s) with class `.body` can be. As the code suggests, this class is intended to create a centered fixed-width wrapper, going below any preceding floats. If there is only one such wrapper on the page, it can be reasonable to use `body` element for it in order to simplify the markup, but it can be not the case on other pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [...] but the weird thing is that body tag is the **only element that is of
>   class "body,"** so I'm not sure why.

You can assign the class `.body` to any element, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" class="body" />
```

Comment: He's saying that class *isn't* being used for anything other than `body`.